# Radgrid insert with dropdown gets null value when I insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, insert, telerik, radgrid

I am using asp.net C# with telerik.
I have radgrid and a button add new record. I press it and fill up the informations but the problem is when I press insert it says that ParentDist and RankLevel can not be null.
In other words I can get the value that i select from the dropdowns. What I do wrong and how I can fix it?

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="ParentDist" FilterControlAltText="Filter ParentDist column" HeaderText="ParentDist" SortExpression="ParentDist" UniqueName="ParentDist">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ParentDistDropDown" runat="server" DataSourceID="ParentSqlDataSource" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="IDnumber" DefaultMessage="Select If Exists">
                    </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ParentDistTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ParentDist") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="RankLevel" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter RankLevel column" HeaderText="RankLevel" SortExpression="RankLevel" UniqueName="RankLevel">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="RankSqlDataSource" DataTextField="RankDescr" DataValueField="RankID" >   </telerik:RadDropDownList>   </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="RankLevelTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RankLevel") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

 InsertCommand="INSERT INTO edmark_distriblist (ParentDist,RankLevel) VALUES ( @ParentDistDropDown, @RadDropDownList1,)"
       >    
<InsertParameters> 

     <asp:Parameter Name="ParentDistDropDown" Type="String" ></asp:Parameter>
      <asp:Parameter Name="RadDropDownList1"  Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
   </InsertParameters>
```

Comment: are you using any codebehind methods, if yes add the codebehind code with question, or just paste the full radgrid aspx definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Bind` expression (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178366%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), as shown here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/form-template-update/defaultcs.aspx. Note the `SelectedValue` property of the dropdown lists.

Or, just use the InsertCommand event, access the controls (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-accessing-cells-and-rows.html) and use their values to compile the query yourself.